# Are questions about language learning software efficiency on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

For example, could I ask "is Duolingo/Rosetta Stone effective in teaching language X?"

Answer (score 11):

We need to be careful about these sorts of questions.

Asking "Is X effective?" isn't a very meaningful question.  To answer it affirmatively, you simply have to show that one person, somewhere, had success with the program.  And how one defines "success" can be a contentious matter, too.

Generally, it would be better to ask for an academic study which examines the effectiveness. Such studies (at least when they're not financed by the company themselves) will typically talk about pros and cons of the system, usually comparing them to some other system (a control group).

TLDR:

> ### Is Duolingo effective?

Not a good question.

> ### Are there studies on the effectiveness of Duolingo?

Improved.

> ### What are the strengths and weaknesses of Duolingo's method?

Perhaps even better.

Comment: Wouldn't any such article have a conclusion on the effectiveness of Duolingo?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: That depends in part on what you mean by "conclusion." "Effectiveness" isn't a linear scale, and it isn't easy to measure.